# React Select doesn't update value on clicking option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, react-select

I have a React Select form, with options loaded after an API call. The initial state value of workshop is set, and it updates after an option is clicked in the form. However, the Select's view does not update. What is more, when the form is submitted, the workshop is successfully saved into the database. What should I do ?

```
renderForm() {
    return (
        <section className="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <form className="col-md-12 col-sm-12"
                  onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit }> 
                // other form-groups
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>
                        Region:
                        <input className="form-control"
                               type="text"
                               value={ this.state.value }
                               onChange={ this.handleRegionChange } required />
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>
                        Workshop:
                    </label>
                    <Select name="form-field-workshop"
                            value={ this.state.workshop }
                            onChange={ this.handleWorkshopChange }
                            options={ this.renderFormWorkshops() }
                            clearable={ false }
                            searchable={ false }
                            required />
                </div>
                <input className="btn btn-default"
                       type="submit"
                       value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </section>
    );
}

// handles the change of state when an option is selected
handleWorkshopChange(value) {
    this.setState({
        workshop: value.label
    });
}

// displays the options in the Select form
renderFormWorkshops() {
    return _.map(this.props.workshops.workshops, (it) => {
        return (
            { value: it.id, label: it.name }
        );  
    });
}
```

Comment: Remove the bracket from this line `value={ this.state.workshop) }`. Should be `value={ this.state.workshop }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
handleWorkshopChange(value) {
    this.setState({
        workshop: value.value
    });
}
```

Comment: It updates the view, but it saves the id. Into the database. I'll do the handling from there. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Shouldnt it be `workshop: value.target.value` ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have it setup correctly in your constructor? There are likely some context issues happening here, this is the correct form to bind context:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.handleWorkshopChange = this.handleWorkshopChange.bind(this);
}
```

If you aren't using arrow functions, you need to bind context for situations that rely on using `this` methods.

Also, you have a stray parentheses here: `value={ this.state.workshop) }`

Comment: Yes, the binding has already been done. Don't mind the stray paranthesis, I didn't see it when posting the question.